# GCC/Clang setting to force -Wpointer-to-int-cast to always log

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc

My issue involves some refactor work that preceded me at my current company.  Long story short is that at one point a property had a type of (I'm guessing) `NSInteger` and was changed to `NSNumber *`.  The current code compiles because of some liberal sprinkling of `(long)` casts throughout the code base, but semantically this is completely different as it operates on the value of the pointer; also the name of the property is not unique and is used thousands of times.

GCC would normally be able to catch this with `-Wpointer-to-int-cast` if the size of the pointer doesn't equal the size of a long, but `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void*)` on both platforms.

My question is there any way with GCC to always log a warning when a pointer type is used as an arithmetic type regardless of whether or not the statement has a cast?

Comment: By "log", you mean produce a diagnostic (at compile time), not log something at runtime, correct?

Comment: right, a diagnostic (warning or error) at compile time

Comment: `/* WarnMePlease.pch */

#ifdef FIXIN_UR_LEGACEEZ
#define long uint8_t
#endif` Might enable you to catch them?

Comment: That could work as a temporary stand-in, though you'll probably get a lot of noise with that method if you use `long`s in a valid way anywhere else in your program. A less palatable but possible less noisy approach is likely to simply search through your project for all `(long)` casts and audit them (or if you're brave, search and delete them all and work from there, removing one compilation warning/error at a time).

Comment: Another thing you might be able to do is to attempt compilation of the project on a 64-bit platform where `int` and `long` don't have the same size, making use of `-Wpointer-to-int-cast`; this might not be possible for your project if you're targeting something like the Apple Watch, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I'm looking at about a thousand instances of `(long)` throughout the project, I do like the idea of mass changing `(long)` to `(int)` which on arm64 should trigger `-Wpointer-to-int-cast`